# Populate JTable Rows to JTextFields in Java from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I am having issues populating my JTextfields when I click on a specific row on my JTable. When I click a row in my JTable, the JTextfields are not populated with their respective values. Please help. Thanks.

My codes:

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            String tbl_click = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());

            try{
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee where EmployeeID = '"+tbl_click+"' ";
                stt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = stt.executeQuery();


                if(rs.next()){
                    int ids = rs.getInt("EmployeeID");
                    id.setText(String.valueOf(ids).trim());

                    String fn = rs.getString("FirstName");
                    fname.setText(fn);

                    String ln = rs.getString("LastName");
                    lname.setText(ln);
                }

                stt.close();

            }catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    scrollPane.setBounds(312, 277, 551, 246);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). Hard code some data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Euh.. did you understand my question ?

Comment: *"did you understand my question ?"* I understand your code issue (you forgot to ask a question).  I'll give further thought to an answer as soon as I see an MCVE.  Voting to close.

Comment: Voting to close ? LOL man ! 
If you cant help, keep your comments to yourself. I dont know what I've missed that you are talking about MCVE or whatever. I have an issue, so I posted it on the forum with my attempts to get a better insight. Thanks

Comment: Ask yourself this question.  What relationship does `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` have with the version of `rs` in the `MouseListener`.  I'm also kind of weirded out with the `MouseListener` on the `JScrollPane` as it's unlikely to ever be triggered

Comment: The DbUtils.resultStToTablModel(rs) retrieves the data from the database, and displays them in the JTable. How to make JScollPane to get triggered when I click on a row?

Answer (score 1):

`MouseEvents` are like rain drops, they fall through the component hierarchy from the top to the bottom until they hit something that is monitoring for them, then they stop.

The likely cause of your problem is the `JTable`, which resides within the `JScrollPane` will prevent the `JScrollPane` from ever been notified of any `MouseEvents`.

I'm "guessing" you need to add the `MouseListener` to the `JTable` instead.  In fact, I'd probably use a `ListSelectionListener`, via the row [`ListSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel()), instead

Comment: Yeah.. When I right click on my JTable component, I have surround it with a JScrollPane.. Now when I right to click to add an event handler, it only directs me to the JScrollPane event handler. There's no options for choosing the JTable MouseListener. What do you suggest?

Comment: For example ? Give me sa sample

Comment: [How to write a MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: I have removed the ScrollPane.. See my updated codes here http://pastebin.com/H6SU0W2u

However, the header is no more visible :( 
How to achieved that to make it displayed?

Comment: You don't want to remove the `JScrollPane`, you just want to add the `MouseListener` to the `JTable`